# What determines whether or not I have hidden a body?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm currently trying to do a Smooth Criminal playthrough of Deus Ex: Human Revolution, where I kill or incapacitate all hostiles while still gaining the Smooth Operator bonus at the end of each mission. Unfortunately, in spite of [cramming bodies into lockers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqKisFDq8_U) and shoving them into the darkest corners of each room, alarms still went off halfway through the first mission, forcing a restart.

What determines whether or not a body is hidden? Is it based on the room that they're in? Or the amount of light shining down on them? Or is it based on something else entirely?

Comment: Isn't it if a camera or a patrol sees a body?

Comment: @Viper_Sb I'm not really sure, but I don't think so. It couldn't have been a patrol since I had literally killed everybody before that point and there were no cameras around yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Viper's right. I've left bodies lying in broad daylight without triggering an alarm, because no one saw them. What mission was it on? Or maybe you did something else that can set an alarm off (such as drop a box on to some lasers or something?) Also, dragging bodies in to vents is quite effective as long as you don't have too many...

Comment: lol @putting them in vents, no wonder it smells so bad in buildings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A body is hidden as long as no one sees the body. This includes cameras and robots.

There's really no such thing as "hidden" there's just "hasn't been found yet".

If you're talking about the very first mission (the prologue) then alarms automatically go off no matter what at certain points. They won't prevent you from getting the Foxiest of the Hounds achievement though, which requires the Smooth Operator bonus whenever you can possibly get it.

Also, there are a couple of other times in the game that alarms will be unpreventable, and again they won't prevent the achievement.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I had forgotten that the alarms went off automatically.

Comment: I don't think you can even get Smooth Operator in the prologue mission.

Comment: @Raven You can't.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that "whenever you can possibly get it" also means that an alarm system has to *exist*. You won't get `Smooth Operator` for passing through alarm-less areas.